# Got confused with self argument in python methods (methods that are not member of any class)

Tags: python, class, self

I am trying to read some github code so that I would be able to modify it to meet my needs. I am struggling in understanding [this file](https://github.com/bendidi/darkflow/blob/5ab192c032be918f868019f73e914e2ef0b8675b/darkflow/net/help.py).
It doesnt contain any `class` keyword but uses `self` keyword inside method definitions.
I guess my question is what are those `self` inside method declaration refer to?
Another relevant question is what is this file, (i.e. is it function) ?

Any comments, suggestions, pointers would greatly help. Thx!

Below is the code that I referenced in the link:

```
"""
tfnet secondary (helper) methods
"""
from ..utils.loader import create_loader
from time import time as timer
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import sys
import cv2
import os
import csv

old_graph_msg = 'Resolving old graph def {} (no guarantee)'

def build_train_op(self):
    self.framework.loss(self.out)
    self.say('Building {} train op'.format(self.meta['model']))
    optimizer = self._TRAINER[self.FLAGS.trainer](self.FLAGS.lr)
    gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(self.framework.loss)
    self.train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(gradients)

def load_from_ckpt(self):
    if self.FLAGS.load < 0: # load lastest ckpt
        with open(self.FLAGS.backup + 'checkpoint', 'r') as f:
            last = f.readlines()[-1].strip()
            load_point = last.split(' ')[1]
            load_point = load_point.split('"')[1]
            load_point = load_point.split('-')[-1]
            self.FLAGS.load = int(load_point)

    load_point = os.path.join(self.FLAGS.backup, self.meta['name'])
    load_point = '{}-{}'.format(load_point, self.FLAGS.load)
    self.say('Loading from {}'.format(load_point))
    try: self.saver.restore(self.sess, load_point)
    except: load_old_graph(self, load_point)

def say(self, *msgs):
    if not self.FLAGS.verbalise:
        return
    msgs = list(msgs)
    for msg in msgs:
        if msg is None: continue
        print(msg)

def load_old_graph(self, ckpt):
    ckpt_loader = create_loader(ckpt)
    self.say(old_graph_msg.format(ckpt))

    for var in tf.global_variables():
        name = var.name.split(':')[0]
        args = [name, var.get_shape()]
        val = ckpt_loader(args)
        assert val is not None, \
        'Cannot find and load {}'.format(var.name)
        shp = val.shape
        plh = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shp)
        op = tf.assign(var, plh)
        self.sess.run(op, {plh: val})

def _get_fps(self, frame):
    elapsed = int()
    start = timer()
    preprocessed = self.framework.preprocess(frame)
    feed_dict = {self.inp: [preprocessed]}
    net_out = self.sess.run(self.out, feed_dict)[0]
    processed = self.framework.postprocess(net_out, frame, False)
    return timer() - start

def camera(self):
    file = self.FLAGS.demo
    SaveVideo = self.FLAGS.saveVideo

    if self.FLAGS.track :
        if self.FLAGS.tracker == "deep_sort":
            from deep_sort import generate_detections
            from deep_sort.deep_sort import nn_matching
            from deep_sort.deep_sort.tracker import Tracker
            metric = nn_matching.NearestNeighborDistanceMetric(
            "cosine", 0.2, 100)
            tracker = Tracker(metric)
            encoder = generate_detections.create_box_encoder(
                os.path.abspath("deep_sort/resources/networks/mars-small128.ckpt-68577"))
        elif self.FLAGS.tracker == "sort":
            from sort.sort import Sort
            encoder = None
            tracker = Sort()
    if self.FLAGS.BK_MOG and self.FLAGS.track :
        fgbg = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()

    if file == 'camera':
        file = 0
    else:
        assert os.path.isfile(file), \
        'file {} does not exist'.format(file)

    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(file)

    if file == 0:
        self.say('Press [ESC] to quit video')

    assert camera.isOpened(), \
    'Cannot capture source'

    if self.FLAGS.csv :
        f = open('{}.csv'.format(file),'w')
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(['frame_id', 'track_id' , 'x', 'y', 'w', 'h'])
        f.flush()
    else :
        f =None
        writer= None
    if file == 0:#camera window
        cv2.namedWindow('', 0)
        _, frame = camera.read()
        height, width, _ = frame.shape
        cv2.resizeWindow('', width, height)
    else:
        _, frame = camera.read()
        height, width, _ = frame.shape

    if SaveVideo:
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
        if file == 0:#camera window
          fps = 1 / self._get_fps(frame)
          if fps < 1:
            fps = 1
        else:
            fps = round(camera.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
        videoWriter = cv2.VideoWriter(
            'output_{}'.format(file), fourcc, fps, (width, height))

    # buffers for demo in batch
    buffer_inp = list()
    buffer_pre = list()

    elapsed = 0
    start = timer()
    self.say('Press [ESC] to quit demo')
    #postprocessed = []
    # Loop through frames
    n = 0
    while camera.isOpened():
        elapsed += 1
        _, frame = camera.read()
        if frame is None:
            print ('\nEnd of Video')
            break
        if self.FLAGS.skip != n :
            n+=1
            continue
        n = 0
        if self.FLAGS.BK_MOG and self.FLAGS.track :
            fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
        else :
            fgmask = None
        preprocessed = self.framework.preprocess(frame)
        buffer_inp.append(frame)
        buffer_pre.append(preprocessed)
        # Only process and imshow when queue is full
        if elapsed % self.FLAGS.queue == 0:
            feed_dict = {self.inp: buffer_pre}
            net_out = self.sess.run(self.out, feed_dict)
            for img, single_out in zip(buffer_inp, net_out):
                if not self.FLAGS.track :
                    postprocessed = self.framework.postprocess(
                        single_out, img, save= False)
                else :
                    postprocessed = self.framework.postprocess(
                        single_out, img,frame_id = elapsed,csv_file=f,csv=writer,mask = fgmask,encoder=encoder,tracker=tracker,save=False)
                if SaveVideo:
                    videoWriter.write(postprocessed)
                if self.FLAGS.display :
                    cv2.imshow('', postprocessed)
            # Clear Buffers
            buffer_inp = list()
            buffer_pre = list()

        if elapsed % 5 == 0:
            sys.stdout.write('\r')
            sys.stdout.write('{0:3.3f} FPS'.format(
                elapsed / (timer() - start)))
            sys.stdout.flush()
        if self.FLAGS.display :
            choice = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if choice == 27:
                break

    sys.stdout.write('\n')
    if SaveVideo:
        videoWriter.release()
    if self.FLAGS.csv :
        f.close()
    camera.release()
    if self.FLAGS.display :
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def to_darknet(self):
    darknet_ckpt = self.darknet

    with self.graph.as_default() as g:
        for var in tf.global_variables():
            name = var.name.split(':')[0]
            var_name = name.split('-')
            l_idx = int(var_name[0])
            w_sig = var_name[1].split('/')[-1]
            l = darknet_ckpt.layers[l_idx]
            l.w[w_sig] = var.eval(self.sess)

    for layer in darknet_ckpt.layers:
        for ph in layer.h:
            layer.h[ph] = None

    return darknet_ckpt
```

Comment: `self` might not be the best choice of name since it can be confusing, it is a valid name for any argument of a function. Even the `self` in methods is only a convention. You can name the first argument differently.

Comment: `self` is not a keyword.  It is a parameter name that _by convention_ refers to the object a method was called on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rather convoluted setup. Basically the functions that are 'stand alone' in the help.py file are subsequently 'patched' into other class definitions (see build.py ...

```
from . import help
...    
class TFNet(object):
    ...
    # imported methods
    say = help.say
    load_from_ckpt = help.load_from_ckpt
    ...
            self.say('\nLoading from .pb and .meta')
    ...    
        if self.FLAGS.load != 0: self.load_from_ckpt()
```

It's really shoddy (imo) not to include any docstrings in the function definitions to explain what the arguments are.

A much more normal way of doing this kind of thing is to have parent class that can be inherited by derived classes.

EDIT in answer to your question in comments, yes. Like this

```
import help

class OddSystem(object):
  say = help.say

o = OddSystem()
o.say('hello world!')

# more normal system would use inheritance, help.py defines a parent class Help
class NormalSystem(help.Help):
  def __init__(self):
    ''' normal definitions etc '''
    pass

n = NormalSystem()
n.say('that is better!')
```

help.py is file in same directory:

```
def say(self, msg):
  print(msg)

class Help(object):
  def say(self, msg):
    print(msg)
```

Comment: Thank you @paddyg, I understand, so it the help.py contains methods that are auxilary for TFNet class (which is inside build.py). It means the self inside help.py refers to TFNet object instance. Am I right?

Comment: @JumabekAlikhanov, yes. Added a simple example you can play about with to see how python works.